# How can I remove a question ban quickly?

Tags: discussion, questions, post-ban

I was recently put on a ban(again) because I asked some poorly received questions, which I deleted because they weren't fit for the site, or were duplicates. I visited [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) and I understand that I can edit my questions to make them more clear(which I did), and post [well-received answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7627726/theprogrammer101?tab=answers&sort=votes) (which I have since my first ban), and I am wondering if there is anything else I can do.

I have edited my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7627726/theprogrammer101?tab=questions&sort=votes) as best as I could, by fixing grammar, content, etc., but the ban is persistent. I understand that the ban should not be lifted easily, because that would defeat the purpose.

I am not asking why I am in a question ban, I am seeking advice for how to remove it quickly. Should I just keep answering questions? Am I in good shape?

Advice on how I can edit my questions is greatly appreciated (or you can edit them yourself if you want).

Comment: If anything I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43336414/578411) still highly confusing. You need to describe better what you're up to, what the context is, what you're currently doing, what does work, what you've tried, what the result was, how that doesn't accomplish what you need, why the answer you linked to and what you incorporated from that still didn't bring you closer to the solution. Given the time you have had so far, I assume you have done extra research and attempts, put those in as well.

Comment: do you have any deleted questions which have received downvoting? even they contribute to the ban..

Comment: Don't forget to see what you can do with your [recently deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/7627726)

Comment: @rene thank you for that advice, I asked this question mainly out of curiosity, but I will make a scenario and clarify my question. Thank you for responding!

Comment: @suraj I know that they contribute to the ban, I am asking how I can best remove a ban quickly.

Comment: @JonClements Should I edit them? Should I reopen them? I thought when they were deleted they weren't seen anyway, so is there a point in editing them? Thank you for your time

Comment: I don't understand your edit, you had a ban that was lifted and now you have it again because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297047/switch-statement-not-waiting-for-input)?

Comment: Yes. I just want to know how I can best make a positive impact on the community(besides answering questions) to get out of the ban.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've upvoted one of your questions, and it lifted the restriction. **Note that you're still *very* close to being restricted again if you get downvoted some more**, so do try to post good questions that would be upvoted from now on, to teach the system that you're asking good questions now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and upvote. This doesn't exactly answer the question though. The question was _"How can I remove a question ban quickly?"_

Comment: @theProgrammer101 You can't do it 'quickly'. The post you read provides you all the details you require.

Comment: I am also suffering from the same problem. I wish I could be able to know, what part of the questions that I have asked had ambiguities that caused people to downvote and eventually banned me.